# How to interpret this __ctype_b based predicate?

Tags: disassembly, decompilation, c, ghidra

I am getting this simplified function from the decomplication results of Ghidra, and I am having a hard time interpreting what the predicate would evaluate to since I do not have access to `__ctype_b` structure, in other words, what is this predicate indicating (eg. no blank spaces, digits only, ect...) ?

```
int myFunc(char myChar) {

    if ((*(unsigned short*)((char)myChar * 2 + __ctype_b) >> 6 & 1) == 0) {
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`_ctype` is a common name for an array with flags used for implementing the `is...` family of C runtime function-like macros from `ctype.h` (`isupper`, `islower`, `isalpha`, `isdigit` and so on). For example, see [this file](https://github.com/syracuse-mscs-2019/simplescalar/blob/master/glibc-1.09/locale/C-ctype_ct.c) from early glibc:

```
CONST unsigned short int __ctype_b_C[] =
  {
    0,
    _IScntrl,
    _IScntrl,
    _IScntrl,
    _IScntrl,
    _IScntrl,
    _IScntrl,
    _IScntrl,
    _IScntrl,
    _IScntrl,
    _IScntrl|_ISspace|_ISblank,
```

If we assume that __ctype_b is an array of shorts, the function seems to be equivalent to:

```
return (__ctype_b[myChar]>>6 & 1)==0;
```

or

```
return (__ctype_b[myChar]& (1<<6))==0;
```

If the bits in the table use [standard values](https://github.com/syracuse-mscs-2019/simplescalar/blob/master/sslittle-na-sstrix/include/ctype.h), `1<<6` corresponds to the `_ISpunct` flag, so the function seems to return  `!ispunct(myChar)`;